# how to setup telnet server machine on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, telnet

I m not able to find any appropriate document to setup telnet configuration on ubuntu 20.04 machine. Please share any resources.

Answer (score 0):

telnet is a command only and a protocol, does not required any setup, only the port(23) should be opened.

In 2023 the telnet should not be in used mostly, because it is insecure tcp connection, and it would be better to disable on host and network devices too.

I recommend to use telnet command with echo.

echo | telnet ip port